# If i try to use variable two times, it is just empty

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = 'https://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html'
html = urlopen(url)



bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
bsObj3 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(bsObj3)
```

This is my Python code.

The result of bsObj2 is Okay. That result is my goal. But, Why I cant't see the result of print(bsObj3)?
It's just Blank.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = 'https://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html'
html = urlopen(url)



bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

url = 'https://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html'
html = urlopen(url)
bsObj3 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(str(bsObj2)==str(bsObj3))
```

The result of this code is True.
But why...?

Why above code (bsObj3) is Blank?

Comment: First block fails because a `HTTPResponse` can only be read once.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the HTML content has been consumed by the first call to BeautifulSoup. So, when you pass *html* (the http.client.HTTPResponse instance) to BeautifulSoup a second time, there's nothing to be read.

You could read the response yourself and use it multiple times like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html"

with urlopen(url) as response:
    if response.status == 200:
        content = response.read()
        bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        bsObj3 = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        assert bsObj2 == bsObj3
```